# I want to make notes. How can I make big document?

Tags: packages, geometry

I am undergraduate mathematics student.I used latex I know all basic of latex. Right now I want to make my notes where I can collect my all Important Theorem,Lemma Definition on Latex.
I want to make notes but can not understand How to make notes on latex.
which packages I need? how can I set my Page? 
I exactly want make collection of my notes just like book structure.
Index, Chapter ,Remark etc It become big document . How can I make such big document.

Comment: I do not understand your question. What do you mean with "short notes"? Can you describe it better?

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE! I think that I have absolutely no idea what you mean when you say "short notes".  Maybe somebody else has an idea?  If not, you need to pin down exactly what that means to you, so that other people will understand your goals.  Perhaps a mock up of what you are working toward?  Do you mean "foot notes"?

Comment: For instance, if one writes `Hello World` in a document that is "short", and it is a "note".  Is that what you mean?

Comment: The standalone document class together with a minipage can be use to create a variable sized document, but you have to specify the width.

Comment: http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html <- Reading the linked document gives you all you need to start. It is not the scope of this site to answer broad and unspecific questions.

Comment: if you need a book structure, why not use book documentclass ? you have theorem environments and all that jazz...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by 'short notes' that you just want to use LaTeX to write down all kinds of mathematical stuff, you really have to learn some LaTeX basics first. I'd start reading here:

LaTeX basics:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Basics

LaTeX and mathematics:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics
https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Mathematical_expressions
https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath

If you meant something different, please provide some examples of what you want to achieve.

Comment: This question has lots of recommendations: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner)